# PHP unlink is asking for a string trying to give it sql string

Tags: php, mysql, path, sql-delete, unlink

I am trying to delete an item from a folder somewhere, and I need to pass in the path of the item to unlink(). For some reason it says I am not returning a string, which I am not sure how to do.

Here is all the code:

```
$filePath = "Select path FROM library where id=" .$id;

    unlink(mysql_query($filePath));

    $library =  "DELETE FROM library WHERE id =" .$id;
    $files =    "DELETE FROM files WHERE library_id=" .$id;
    mysql_query($library) or die('Unable to update using sql '.$library.' '.mysql_error($link));
    mysql_query($files) or die('Unable to update using sql '.$files.' '.mysql_error($link));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_query returns a statement HANDLE, not a string. You need to fetch a row from the result:

```
$res = mysql_query($filePath) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
unlink($row['path']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it :D I tried doing something similar earlier, and it did not work, ill go over my work and see what went wrong, but that fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns a resource, not a string.

Use:

```
$query = mysql_query($filePath);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$path = $result['path'];
unlink($path);
```

The process:

1. Query the database and store the resource handle in a variable (`$query`).
2. Fetch the row (if there is only one) and store the row in `$result`.
3. Fetch the value for the `path` column.
4. Use that value to delete the file.

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for detailed information and usage notes.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

mysql_query does not actually return the values of that your query selected, but a result resource. You can use the function mysql_result(, , ) to get the wanted information.